# Submit some activity in advance to start a session - botium with directline

Tags: node.js, direct-line-botframework, botium-box

There was a change in our chatBot and now for me to start a conversation and send questions with the bot I need to say “hi” first, how do i do this with DIRECTLINE3_WELCOME_ACTIVITY ? It’s possible? If yes, how to implement this in botium.json??

```
...
"DIRECTLINE3_WELCOME_ACTIVITY": {
  "type": "event",
  "name": "webchat/join",
  "value": {
    "language": "de-DE"
  },
  "channelData": {
    "kb": "demo"
  }
},
```